# Use standard POST (form submit) with dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

I want to upload a CSV file (via Drag & Drop) and then have a results page display the contents. I need the dropzone to NOT use ajax and instead upload like a standard browser form.

Here's what I tried so far:

upload.php:

```
<form action="results.php" class="dropzone" id="filedrop"></form>
<script>
    Dropzone.options.filedrop = {
        init: function () {
            this.on("complete", function (file) {
                console.log("done");
                $('#filedrop').trigger('submit');
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

results.php:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
var_dump($_POST);
```

Unfortunately when I upload a file, the form submits but it just shows `array(0) { } array(0) { }` (both `$_FILES` and `$_POST` are empty).

I know I could return data via ajax and display it on the same page as the dropzone. But, since I'll be working with large CSV files, I would like to avoid that.

Comment: forgive my ignorance...what's the point in using dropzone if you don't want to take advantage of ajax ?

Comment: Drag & Drop is still faster than browsing your desktop for the file.

Comment: But you can drag and drop without the need for any library.